# Django Test Redirect to login with next parameter

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

I'm trying to Test non-login user redirect to login url. Is there a way to pass get parameter (example 'next') to reverse_lazy? I'm using class-based views.

```
class SecretIndexViewTest(TestCase):
    url = reverse_lazy('secret_index')
    login_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    client = Client()

    def test_http_status_code_302(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertRedirects(response, self.login_url,)
```

above fails with

```
Response redirected to '/login?next=/secret', expected '/login'Expected '/login?next=/secret' to equal '/login'.
```

tried

```
class SecretIndexViewTest(TestCase):
    url = reverse_lazy('secret_index')
    login_url = reverse_lazy('login', kwargs={'next': url)
    client = Client()

    def test_http_status_code_302(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertRedirects(response, self.login_url,)
```

result is no reverse match

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' with keyword arguments '{'next': '/secret'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['/login$']
```

changing kwargs to args will result the same error.

I know I can handle it with below, but I'm looking for a better solution.

```
self.assertRedirects(response, self.login_url + f"?next={self.url}",)
```

or

```
login_url = reverse_lazy('login') + f"?next={url}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [mentioned in the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against), `reverse` (and `reverse_lazy`) do not include GET parameters, so your string formatting example is one of the simplest solutions.

> The URLconf searches against the requested URL, as a normal Python string. This does not include GET or POST parameters, or the domain name.
>
> For example, in a request to https://www.example.com/myapp/, the URLconf will look for myapp/.
>
> In a request to https://www.example.com/myapp/?page=3, the URLconf will look for myapp/.
>
> The URLconf doesn’t look at the request method. In other words, all request methods – POST, GET, HEAD, etc. – will be routed to the same function for the same URL.

If you are worried about encoding your query strings, you can use the tools in the [`urllib.parse` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting) such as `urllib.parse.urlencode` to encode your queries before building the full URL by concatenating the path from `reverse` and the encoded query parameters.

For simple cases such as tests where you know exactly what data is being passed in, I would be inclined to stick with the simple string formatting.

Comment: I'm a newbie to Django, but I found this surprising enough to check the Django tests, and it is indeed [how](https://github.com/django/django/blob/85b52d22fd2841c34e95b3a80d6f2b668ce2f160/tests/auth_tests/test_views.py#L619) [they](https://github.com/django/django/blob/85b52d22fd2841c34e95b3a80d6f2b668ce2f160/tests/auth_tests/test_views.py#L714) [do](https://github.com/django/django/blob/85b52d22fd2841c34e95b3a80d6f2b668ce2f160/tests/auth_tests/test_views.py#L744) [it](https://github.com/django/django/blob/85b52d22fd2841c34e95b3a80d6f2b668ce2f160/tests/auth_tests/test_views.py#L762).